# iPad 2 stuck connecting to router

Tags: ipad

Yesterday I was looking through my mail, then suddenly I no longer had connection to my router. My son's iPad 2 was working well and any other computers and laptops could still access the Internet fine. Thinking this was only temporary and was late at night already, I waited for the next day to see if it resolved itself the next day. It did not. I hard rebooted the iPad 2, restarted the router, and tried to refresh the WiFi list by making the iPad 2 forget my home network and retyping the password. No success. I did an All Settings reset through the General menu and the problem continues to persist and I am thinking I might have to reformat the iPad 2 or sent it to the Apple Store as a last resort.

When I check the WiFi settings, it is able to see the name of my router and many others, and when I attempt to connect to it, it simply is attempting to connect, but is simply stuck there.

Any other methods to try would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try restoring your router to factory defaults. I had a similar problem (multiple wireless and wired devices successfully connected to the router except an iPhone and resetting the iPhone did not resolve the problem) that was fixed by resetting the router to factory defaults.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @patrix This seems to be a fine answer to me. It might not work, but it seems like a good thing to try.

Comment: The edited version is much better :-)